# Disable F7 caret browsing prompt in UWP development

Tags: xamarin, uwp

We are developing a Xamarin application focused on mobile and desktop (UWP). We found that F7 key is bounded to prompt a dialog about "caret browsing".

Looks like the implementation of this functionality is application dependent and the dialog only provides a setter for this configuration (please correct me if I am wrong).

We do not intent to implement such behavior and want to use this key to other end (our web app uses it and we are replicating the same functionality - long time customers are familiarized with this).

After hours searching, I could not find a way to permanently disable the prompt. It really does not make any sense why MS provide this dialog if we do not want to implement it!

Has anyone managed to solve this problem and can help us?

Comment: same Question in MS Forums (sadly wrong closed currently): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/76759/disable-f7-caret-browsing-prompt-in-uwp-developmen.html

Comment: We have dropped UWP development and went back to old Windows Forms using a modern UI Framework. UWP seems to fit only really basic applications, there is too many limitations we have found. Xamarin for UWP is even worst.